# Using WSO2 IOT is it possible to restrict some sites through smartphone devices?

Tags: android, wso2, iot

Using WSO2 IOT is it possible to restrict some sites through smartphone devices?
Has anyone implemented this implementation?
Need to determine that devices access only certain sites? This lock can be made
By WSO2 IOT, EMM, or by android or in the android browser?
I need to leave the smarphones with restricted access, accessing only the defined sites

Comment: I honestly doubt you can make such a restriction. What you can do is allowing to run only specific applications (e.g.your own custom app) accessing the defined sites through a webview component

Comment: What you can do is you can install the system app to the device and write your own policy by customizing the system app. But I highly doubt whether you can enforce such a restriction. The user might be still able to use a proxy service or a tunnel to browse websites.